# Is it possible to capture GPU display output using a capture card?

Tags: video, graphics-card, hdmi, video-capture

For a period of time I was left without a monitor but I wanted to configure some BIOS settings on my PC. I only have a MacBook and a capture card. I thought I could simply connect my GPU's HDMI output to the capture card, and then connect the capture card to my MacBook to "see" the HDMI output of my PC and thus control it like that.

However, when I tried this, it turned out that nothing was shown on the capture card. To check if the capture card was working properly, I connected it to my camera's HDMI output port using a mini-HDMI to HDMI cable. The capture card read my camera's screen just fine. I tried connecting the GPU's output to the capture card again. Again, nothing was shown.

Why does the GPU not output any video signal to my capture card? Does it not do that because it realizes the capture cards is not a display? How can I "force" my GPU to output video to the capture card regardless?

Comment: Your PC's resolution and refresh rate might be set too high for the capture card.

Comment: It's supposed to be a 4K capture card, and I've only ever used it with a 1080p monitor anyway. And not even the BIOS shows up, which shouldn't cause issues with high resolution